# dataflow from Azure blob storage to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerquery, data-warehouse

I know basically zero about Azure Blob Storage, but I'm working on a PowerBI report that retrieves CSV files from Azure Blob storage and parses them into tables in the PowerBI model. This seems like an insanely resource intensive way to do this - why not parse the CSV files and write the results to properly indexed database tables, and then I can use aggregations (because it's like 9 million records, and my matrix is slowwwwwww).

is that a viable solution?

Comment: are you talking about the ADF dataflows?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at Power BI [Datamart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/datamarts/datamarts-overview) over Dataflow.

Comment: All I want to do is basically make the CSV ingestion permanent. As it is now, I think PowerBI tries to re-run the transformations any time I try to go near the PowerQuery stuff, which is what I don't want. I just want to persist the transformations somewhere. Way back like 6 months ago, that was the right way to do it, I think. You know, back when Synapse was Azure Data Warehouse. Then I can do what Phil Seamark is suggesting here: https://dax.tips/2021/09/06/intro-to-power-bi-aggregations/  Honestly, I just want this junk to work.

Comment: Based on that, then Dataflow is a good option.

Comment: okay, so basically create the PowerQuery to merge all that, and then dump the the result to a permanent (indexed) table? (Then if I have to push back to DirectQuery, it should be fast, right?

Comment: Oh, like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj5mrtTsR1M

Answer (score 1):

use data flows in ADF to do it. Just like in the video. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj5mrtTsR1M) Should work a champ. Then I can have all of my data in my datamart or whatever, and then I can create an aggregation table, and finally, include the data in my report without having to unpack it all every time.